# Tomcat gives page not found when accessed for second time on any Browser

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-restcontroller

I have built a Spring MVC project that has REST services. I have deployed it on TOMCAT. 
When I use the url on my local machine like: **"localhost:8080/rmtest/questions.do?testId=1 "** , it give the correct Json response. No matter how many times I hit that URL, I get the correct json response.

But when I hit it from different machines by using the url : **"http://192.168.1.178:8080/rmtest/questions.do?testId=1"** , it works correctly for the first time and gives the correct json response. But if I try to hit the same URL again on that machine after some time, it is not allowed. I get a "Webpage Not Found".

Any idea on why this might be happening ?

I have tried this on 2 different Laptops and 2 mobile phones apart from the system running the server, and I get similar results on each of those systems/mobiles.

Comment: Can you post the log from tomcat? ie `$tomcat_dir/logs/catalina.out`? seems like the application/server crashes on first view. After that the server is down, hence results in a 404

Comment: The server cannot be down because, even if on one device the "website not available" appears, i can still connect to the server from a device which hasn't been connected to it before.

Comment: Any redirect ? Are you sure the second try is made with exactly the same URL ? I'm a bit confused by your URL *.do make me think of Struts (??) a rest URL scheme would rather be /rmtest/questions/1 ?

Comment: `Webpage Not Found` is responsed from server with(as) a server status? or the client could not connect to the server because server is either down or not responding, so a client error?! I think you have logical error in your code, show some code.

Comment: @user5266804 , the full error i get when i try to connect it for the second time is : "could not load the webpage because 192.160.1.178 took too long to respond." so, its a connection timed out error.

Comment: @jps , i know its not the usual convention, but NO Struts involved. and yes, i have been using the same URL

Comment: Share the servlet code, the issue sounds like logical issue with your servlet. @AkshayPai

Comment: So, I have fixed the issue. I don't know what exactly went wrong but, this is what i did. 

In the tomcat server, i deleted the existing app that was deployed and re deployed the war file. And it worked fine. The error however was happening but very rarely. It might be because of some network issues, but i'm not entirely sure. As of now, its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check for firewall setting. This may be a network issue nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was that Tomcat was not correctly Deploying the WAR file which lead to many   problems and not just the one mentioned above. The reason to why it was incorrectly deploying the WAR file is not known, but I deleted tomcat an installed it again and deployed the same war file and it worked fine.